# how to pass the "..." parameters in the parent function to its two children functions in r

Tags: r, function

I am trying to pass a set of parameters into a function. This function has two sub functions that take part of the above set of parameters.

In the following "SIMPLIFIED" example
`f_combined` is a function that takes `...`
I would like to make the following function call such that `xx` is passed to `f_sqr` and `yy` is passed to `f_plus`:

```
f_combined(xx = 2, yy = 2)
```

but it would give me an error:

```
Error in f_sqr(...) : unused argument (yy = 2)
```

any suggustions?

```
f_sqr <- function(xx =1){
  xx ^ 2
}

f_plus <- function(yy =1){
  yy + 1
}

f_combined <- function(...){
  f_sqr(...) + f_plus(...)
}
```

Comment: Can't you put the default arguments in the combined functions instead of using `...`?

Comment: Not really. 
For a simple function, Yes, we can do that. 
But I am really looking for a much more complicated function that potentially combines many functions with many parameters. Think of a function like ggplot().

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Alternatively you would query a function's `formals()` to see what named parameters it is expecting and pass along only those. If the "child" function accepts `...`, then we will pass along all arguments. This method would not work well for positional arguments.

```
f_combined <- function(..., .fns =list(f_sqr, f_plus), .reduce=`+`){
   dots <- list(...)
   Reduce(.reduce, lapply(.fns, function(f) {
       if ("..." %in% names(formals(f))) {
           do.call(f, dots)
       } else if ( any( names(dots) %in% names(formals(f)) ) ) {
           do.call(f, dots[names(formals(f))])
       } else {
           f()
       }
   }))
}
```

Here i've set the two functions to run as a parameter (`.fns=list(f_sqr, f_plus)`) so they can be easily changed or more can be effortlessly added. I've also set a parameter specifying how to combine those values should you want to do something other than sum them (`.reduce='+'`). But the basic idea is find the best set of mathching named parameters and pass them along. Since your "child" function have default values for their parameters as well, they will run when you pass along no parameters as well.

Here are some example calls

```
f_combined()
# [1] 3
f_combined(xx=2)
# [1] 6
f_combined(yy=2)
# [1] 4
f_combined(xx = 2, yy = 2)
# [1] 7
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It was very useful for me. I think it may be improved a bit using (when f has more arguments than ...): `do.call(f, dots[intersect(names(dots), names(formals(f)))])`

Answer (score 14):

You can either access `...` as a named pairwise list or access it by order `..n`

```
f_sqr <- function(xx =1){xx ^ 2}
f_plus <- function(yy =1){yy + 1}

f_combined <- function(...){
  print(f_sqr(list(...)$xx))
  print(f_plus(list(...)$yy))
  print(f_sqr(..1))
  print(f_plus(..2))
}
f_combined( yy = 1, xx = 10)

[1] 100 (element with name xx of the list ...)
[1] 2 (element with name yy of the list ...)
[1] 1 (the first argument in the list ...)
[1] 11 (the second argument in the list ...)
```

Output of `?"..."`

> 10.4 The ‘...’ argument
>
> Another frequent requirement is to allow one function to pass on
>   argument settings to another. For example many graphics functions use
>   the function par() and functions like plot() allow the user to pass on
>   graphical parameters to par() to control the graphical output. (See
>   The par() function, for more details on the par() function.) This can
>   be done by including an extra argument, literally ‘...’, of the
>   function, which may then be passed on. An outline example is given
>   below.
>
> ```
>  fun1 <- function(data, data.frame, graph=TRUE, limit=20, ...) {
>    [omitted statements]
>    if (graph)
>      par(pch="*", ...)
>    [more omissions]
>  }
> ```
>
> Less frequently, a function will need to refer to components of ‘...’.
>   The expression list(...) evaluates all such arguments and
>   returns them in a named list, while ..1, ..2, etc. evaluate them one
>   at a time, with ‘..n’ returning the n'th unmatched argument.

Comment: This will fail if one of the two arguments is omitted. For instance `f_combined(yy=1)` will not give the expected result.

Comment: @nico, Since the OP is asking how to use `...`, that is my understanding of how to use it. That is it. Seems like MrFlick has figured out a solution that is more stable.

Comment: Well, what is the point of using `...` if you need to specify both parameters and cannot use the defaults? To be honest, I think the easiest way would be to have, as I commented above, `f_combined <- function(xx=1, yy=2)` and have the two other functions without defaults.