# Simplest way to create wrapper functions?

Tags: r

This should be really basic but I'm totally new to defining functions in R.

Sometimes I want to define a function which simply consists of wrapping a base function in one or more other functions.

E.g., I wrote `prop.table2` which basically accomplishes `prop.table(table(...))`.

The hitch that I see is that I also want my wrapper function to take the optional arguments of any of the subfunctions and pass them appropriately,

E.g.,

```
prop.table2(TABLE, useNA = "always", margin = 2) =
  prop.table(table(TABLE, useNA = "always"), margin = 2)
```

What's the simplest way to accomplish something like this (assuming there's no conflict in argument names, etc)? My baseline approach is to simply paste all of the optional arguments to each subfunction into the main function definition, i.e., defining:

```
prop.table2 <- function(..., exclude = if (useNA == "no") c(NA, NaN),
                        useNA = c("no", "ifany", "always"), dnn = list.names(...),
                        deparse.level = 1, margin = NULL)
```

---

Let's work from this example for concreteness:

```
dt <- data.table(id = sample(5, size = 100, replace = TRUE),
                 grp = letters[sample(4, size = 100, replace=TRUE)])
```

I want to replicate the following with my function:

```
dt[ , prop.table(table(grp, id, useNA = "always"), margin = 1)]

      id
grp             1          2          3          4          5       <NA>
  a    0.28571429 0.10714286 0.17857143 0.25000000 0.17857143 0.00000000
  b    0.12000000 0.28000000 0.08000000 0.12000000 0.40000000 0.00000000
  c    0.23076923 0.23076923 0.15384615 0.19230769 0.19230769 0.00000000
  d    0.23809524 0.19047619 0.23809524 0.28571429 0.04761905 0.00000000
  <NA>
```

Here's where I'm at now, which still doesn't quite work; the idea was to split everything into those arguments which `prop.table` accepts and then pass the rest to `table`, but I'm still struggling.

```
prop.table2 <- function(...) {
  dots <- list(...)
  dots2 <- dots
  dots2[intersect(names(dots2), names(formals(prop.table)))] <- NULL
  dots3 <- dots2
  dots3[intersect(names(dots3), names(formals(table)))] <- NULL
  dots2[names(dots2) == ""] <- NULL
  prop.table(table(dots3, dots2), margin = list(...)$margin)
}
```

Comment: you could use a list and do.call, `function(..., prop.param = list()) do.call(prop.table, c(table(...), prop.param))`

Comment: It would get complicated if the sub functions share parameter names. You are safest controling the passing yourself, but here's a question that did inspect the formals of a function to see which parameters to pass along: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25749661/how-to-pass-the-parameters-in-the-parent-function-to-its-two-children-func/25750688#25750688

Comment: @baptiste is there a typo? That's not working for me, e.g.: `dt<-data.table(id=sample(10,size=100,rep=T),grp=letters[sample(10,size=100,rep=T)]); dt[,prop.table2(id,grp,prop.param=list(margin=1))]`

Comment: @MrFlick inspired by your other solution I thought something along the lines of `prop.table2<-function(...){prop.table(table(...),margin=list(...)$margin)}` would work, but I can't seem to finagle it--the problem seems to be in passing "..." to `table`

Comment: @MichaelChirico When you have `table(...)`, that's passing everything to table. You can't easily split the `...`s. It's all or nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing a list() in my earlier comment, the following should work,

```
prop.table2 <- function(..., prop.param = list()) 
                 do.call(prop.table, c(list(table(...)), prop.param))

# with the example provided
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(id=sample(5,size=100,replace=T),
                 grp=letters[sample(4,size=100,replace=T)])
dt[,prop.table2(grp,id,useNA="always",prop.param=list(margin=1))]
      id
grp             1          2          3          4          5       <NA>
  a    0.10714286 0.28571429 0.14285714 0.25000000 0.21428571 0.00000000
  b    0.09090909 0.18181818 0.30303030 0.15151515 0.27272727 0.00000000
  c    0.38095238 0.14285714 0.19047619 0.09523810 0.19047619 0.00000000
  d    0.11111111 0.22222222 0.44444444 0.16666667 0.05555556 0.00000000
  <NA>
```

Edit: the OP suggests this modification [based on previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4128401/471093) to filter `...` based on their names,

```
prop.table2 <- function(...){
  dots <- list(...)
  passed <- names(dots)
  # filter args based on prop.table's formals
  args <- passed %in% names(formals(prop.table))
  do.call('prop.table', c(list(do.call('table', dots[!args])), 
          dots[args]))
}

# with the example provided
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(id=sample(5,size=100,replace=T),
                 grp=letters[sample(4,size=100,replace=T)])
dt[,prop.table2(grp,id,useNA="always",margin=1)]
      id
grp             1          2          3          4          5       <NA>
  a    0.10714286 0.28571429 0.14285714 0.25000000 0.21428571 0.00000000
  b    0.09090909 0.18181818 0.30303030 0.15151515 0.27272727 0.00000000
  c    0.38095238 0.14285714 0.19047619 0.09523810 0.19047619 0.00000000
  d    0.11111111 0.22222222 0.44444444 0.16666667 0.05555556 0.00000000
  <NA>
```

Comment: Still not quite working. I think the problem is you're not passing arguments carefully to the second subfunction; I've added a working example to the body of the question so we're on the same footing about what to aim for.

Comment: dunno, as far as i can tell it works

Comment: maybe I'm using it wrong, could you paste a code snippet that's running?

Comment: the above already contains your example and its expected result

Comment: sorry, i must have missed this in my morning grog. i'll double-check this when i get back to a computer with a compiler.

Comment: OK, got it. I'm still not satisfied. How would this generalize to, say, `f<-function(allparams){g(h(i(...,iparams),hparams),gparams)}`? Also, I'd prefer to write f(x,y,z) instead of having to name `prop.param` (or anything shorter), as it feels more natural.

Comment: this question has been asked _many_ times, I was just a bit too lazy to search for duplicates. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124900/is-there-a-way-to-use-two-statements-in-a-function-in-r) might be closer to what you want

Comment: there's still a problem, in that the main argument of `table` is `...`; it's still not clear to me how to pass that through _and_ match the optional `table` arguments.

Comment: @MichaelChirico you should probably post your own answer, since your edit changes this one substantially

Comment: OK; I thought it was close enough to edit yours and give you credit for the answer, considering 95% did come from your suggestions. Thank you by the way.

Comment: Hmm unfortunately I can't seem to add any new answers while it's marked as duplicate.

Comment: didn't think of that, sorry. I've added a version of your suggested code

Comment: ah even better. I knew there was a way to skip the `dots2` step...

Answer (score 2):

You may use a functional with unspecified arguments (...). A functional is a higher order function that accepts a function as an argument (eg `lapply()`).

```
prop.table2 <- function(f, ...) {
  f(...)
}

a <- rep(c(NA, 1/0:3), 10)
table(round(a, 2), exclude = NULL)
#0.33  0.5    1  Inf <NA> 
#  10   10   10   10   10 

prop.table2(table, round(a, 2), exclude = NULL)
#0.33  0.5    1  Inf <NA> 
#  10   10   10   10   10
```

@ MichaelChirico

Sorry that below is as much as I can think of at the moment.

A composite function is created, `compose()`, and the margin argument of `prop.table()` should be determined in it.

Specific functions (*f* and *g*) are added in `prop()`.

Then additional arguments of `table()` can be added.

Note that, due to missing values, it'll cause an error if *margin* is set to be 2 as your example.

```
a <- rep(c(NA, 1/0:3), 10)

compose <- function(f, g, margin = NULL) {
    function(...) f(g(...), margin)
}
prop <- compose(prop.table, table)
prop(round(a, 2), exclude = NULL)

# 0.33  0.5    1  Inf <NA> 
# 0.2  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.2
```

@MichaelChirico

Below is the second edit.

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1237)
dt <- data.table(id=sample(5,size=100,replace=T),
                 grp=letters[sample(4,size=100,replace=T)])

compose <- function(f, g, margin = 1) {
    function(...) f(g(...), margin)
}
prop <- compose(prop.table, table)

dt[,prop(grp, id, useNA="always")]

#id
#grp           1          2          3          4          5       <NA>
#a    0.23529412 0.17647059 0.11764706 0.23529412 0.23529412 0.00000000
#b    0.11764706 0.29411765 0.05882353 0.17647059 0.35294118 0.00000000
#c    0.11538462 0.19230769 0.30769231 0.15384615 0.23076923 0.00000000
#d    0.34782609 0.13043478 0.13043478 0.17391304 0.21739130 0.00000000
#<NA>
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this solves the problem... 1) I'm writing the new function to avoid having to rewrite the names of all the sub-functions every time and 2) you're not using `prop.table`.

Comment: I think we're off on what I'm going for--what your code seems tailored to is writing a _general_ function designed to compose any two _given_ functions; instead, what I have in mind is a _specific_ function which is shorthand for the composition of two _specific_ functions.

Comment: I consider `prop()` is a proper shorthand of the two functions. 1) By `compose()`, the only extra argument of `prop.table()`, can be specified, which is `margin`. 2) By `prop()`, any argument of `table()` can be specified. It is up to you whether to adjust some arguments of `table()` and, if nothing is adjusted, default values will just be taken. In this way, you don't need to bring all optional arguments or arguments with default values into your function. To me, `prop()` is specific enough.

Comment: This helps me, thank you