# How to avoid re-listing internal function arguments in wrapper function in R?

Tags: r, function, arguments, parameter-passing, wrapper

Let's say I have a function with with many arguments (e.g., `plot()`).

I want to add a bit of functionality to that function by creating a wrapper function around that function.

- Random example:

  ```
  plot.new <- function() {
    windows(width = 10, height = 10)
    plot()
  }
  ```

My question: **How do I make it so that the internal function's arguments can be provided in my new wrapper function?**

- How can I do so without retyping all the argument names from the internal function when defining my wrapper function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [three dots ellipsis](https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-three-dots-ellipsis/)

```
plot.new <- function(...) {
  windows(width = 10, height = 10)
  plot(...)
}
```

If you want to explicitly include any of the internal function arguments in the wrapper function list, you'll have to explicitly define that argument in the internal function as well:

```
plot.new <- function(x, ...) {
    graphics.off() #OPTIONAL
    windows(width = 10, height = 10)
    plot(x = x, ...)
}

#USAGE
plot.new(x = rnorm(10), y = rnorm(10), pch = 19)
```

[And here is more discussion on using `…` to distribute the arguments to multiple internal functions.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42007678/7128934)

Comment: Do they need to be present in both argument list locations?

Comment: What happens if I "reuse" an argument name (or choose to define just one of the internal function's arguments)? For example: `plot.new <- function(x,...) { plot(...) }`

Comment: Last question: can I place the ellipsis anywhere in the wrapper function argument list? Ex: `function(...,z)` vs `function(z,...)`? And if so, will that dicatate the "ordering" of the arguments if I choose to not name them when running the wrapper function?