# R: How to use ellipsis (...) in function argument if the function contains multiple inner ellipsed functions?

Tags: r, function, arguments

Let's say I create custom function:

```
foo <- function(bar) { 
  c(x=bar, y=bar) }
```

I then create a custom "wrapper" function that contains this function and some other function:

```
foo2 <- function(...) {
  dat <- foo(...)
  plot(x = dat[1], y = dat[2], ...)
}
```

I've used `...` assuming both functions would have multiple arguments in a real world application.

- However, note that **two *different* inner functions have an `...`**.

Although this appears to work, it's not without warnings:

```
> foo2(bar=1)
Warning messages:
1: In plot.window(...) : "bar" is not a graphical parameter
2: In plot.xy(xy, type, ...) : "bar" is not a graphical parameter
3: In axis(side = side, at = at, labels = labels, ...) :
  "bar" is not a graphical parameter
4: In axis(side = side, at = at, labels = labels, ...) :
  "bar" is not a graphical parameter
5: In box(...) : "bar" is not a graphical parameter
6: In title(...) : "bar" is not a graphical parameter
```

Although R seems to be smart enough to apply unassigned arguments (i.e., those accounted for using the `...`) in my wrapper function to the appropriate inner function, it also appears as though the wrapper function *still tries* to apply the unassigned arguments to *both* inner functions.

- This results in a warning if one of the unassigned arguments (*in this case* `bar`) does not exist as a named argument for one of the inner functions (*in this case* `plot()`).

My question(s):

1. Is there a way to avoid having these warnings appear?
2. Is this even the appropriate way to approach this issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16774946/passing-along-ellipsis-arguments-to-two-different-functions or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080972/using-multiple-ellipses-arguments-in-r or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42007678/using-multiple-three-dot-ellipsis-in-r might be helpful

Comment: @thelatemail Thanks! I looked forever for useful posts, but didn't find any of these. After rummaging through those links and posts linked to them, I think the most useful similar post is here: [Is there a way to use two '…' statements in a function in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4124900/4581200)

Comment: However, that post is from 7 years ago. I wonder if there is a more straightforward / elegant approach to this now??