How to pass unknown number of arguments to multiple functions in R
I want to pass an unknown number of arguments to two functions. These functions might have a defined number of arguments when defined, but that could change if I need to change them.
More concretely, I have two functions f1 and f2:
f1 <- function(a, b) { (some code) }
f2 <- function(x, y, z) { (some code) }

Here f1 and f2 have two and three arguments respectively, but (for example) I might need to use some other function f3 instead of f2:
f3 <- function(s, ...) { (some code) }

f3 might have a different number of arguments than f2.
I also have a function f, which will have f1 and f2 as arguments, and will also have the arguments of f1 and f2 themselves as arguments:
f <- function(arg1, arg2, f1, f2, (arguments of f1), (arguments of f2)) { (some code) }

But I don´t know how to pass an unknown number of parameters to f1 AND f2.
I don't know if I can use ..., because I don´t know a priori how to separate ... into the arguments of f1 and the arguments of f2. I also can´t use nargs since it only counts the number of arguments in ... but I still don´t know at the start how to separate them. Maybe there´s a way I can have multiple ...'s like this:
f <- function(f1, f1, ...1, ...2) {

some code using 

f1(...1) 

and 

f2(...2)

}

?

Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42007678/using-multiple-three-dot-ellipsis-in-r

If you can pass the arguments of f1 and f2 into f as lists (I don't know if this is amenable to how you will be using f), you could do something like:
f <- function(f1, f2, f1.args, f2.args) { 
  # some code using
  do.call(f1, f1.args)
  # and
  do.call(f2, f2.args)
}

and you'd call it like
f(f1, f2, list(a, b), list(x, y, z))


"I don't know if I can use ..."... I think you can, and doing so will allow you not to worry about which argument "belongs" to which child function.  The key is to add ... as an argument to each of the child functions.
foo <- function(a, b, ...) {
  paste0("Foo - a: ", a, "; b: ", b)
}

bar <- function(x, y, z, ...) {
  paste0("Bar - x: ", x, "; y: ", y, "; z: ", z)
}

baz <- function(...) {
  list(...)
}

f <- function(f1, f2, ...) {
  print(f1(...))
  print(f2(...))
}

f(f1 = foo, f2 = bar, a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, x = "dog", y = "cat", z = "bird", unused = TRUE)
[1] "Foo - a: 1; b: 2"
[1] "Bar - x: dog; y: cat; z: bird"

f(f1 = foo, f2 = baz, a = 1, b = 2, m = 1, n = 10)
[1] "Foo - a: 1; b: 2"
$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] 2

$m
[1] 1

$n
[1] 10

If a child function doesn't support ..., just wrap it one that does:
foo1 <- function(a, b) {
  paste0("Foo - a: ", a, "; b: ", b)
}

foo1Wrapper <- function(...) {
  args <- list(...)
  foo1(a = args$a, b = args$b)
}

f(f1 = foo1Wrapper, f2 = baz, a = 1, b = 2, m = 1, n = 10)
[1] "Foo - a: 1; b: 2"
$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] 2

$m
[1] 1

$n
[1] 10

An alternative form for the wrapper could be
foo1Wrapper <- function(a, b, ...) {
  foo1(a = a, b = b)
}

with the same result
